Calculate SUMPRODUCT with multiple column criteria and one row criteria




A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L







ratio
tested
2023
2024
2025

RowCrit
ColCrit1
ColCrit2



2
Brand A
P1
7%
yes
500
70
60

2023
Brand A
P1



3
Brand A
P2
8%
yes
100
47
300


Brand B




4
Brand A
P2
10%
yes
800
21
200







5
Brand B
P1
5%
yes
90
56
150







6
Brand C
P4
3%
no
45
700
790







7
Brand C
P2
8%
no
600
150
40

Result
39.5




8
Brand D
P1
12%
yes
900
90
980







9
Brand D
P1
20%
yes
125
854
726







10
Brand D
P3
19%
yes
70
860
614







11
Brand D
P3
2%
yes
842
250
85







12
Brand E
P4
6%
no
300
324
450









In Cell J7 I want to calculate the SUMPRODUCT based on multiple column criteria and one row criteria:

The criteria for the row you can find in Cell I2 
The criteria for the columns you can find in Range J2:J3 and Range K2:K3. 

In the example above the result is:
J7 = 500x7% + 90x5% = 39.5


So far I have been able to extract the SUM based on the criteria using this formula:
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(I2;C1:G1)*COUNTIF(J2:J3;A2:A12)*COUNTIF(K2:K3;B2:B12);C2:G12))

However, I have no clue how to change this formula so it calculates the SUMPRODUCT and includes all the criteria both for column and row?

Since you are online, please confirm how do you consider the ratio column, also the existing formula of yours returns 126 and not 39.5 as I assume, you want it to be dynamic, in your second last post you have categorically mentioned initial column and year 2024 for row criteria, but in this one you haven't. Could you confirm?

When I calculate 500x7% + 90x5% I get 39.5 as result. In this post I removed the multiple row criteria to reduce the complexity of the question and only have one criteria for the row. Therefore, the row criteria is only 2024.

Yes that is what I wanted to confirm, but your existing formula doesn't returns 39.5 instead it returns 126 just to clarify. But if you want to take the ratio column you need to state that otherwise i am not sure how is it going to account for. Also for the year 2024 --> Brand A + P1 val is 70 and ratio is 7% while for --> Brand B + P1 it is 56 and 5% you will need to verify your post and typos. If you are saying 500 and 90 then it should be Year 2023

Ah sorry. Now I got it. I edited the question and changed the row criteria to 2023.

Are you able to understand what I am trying to say. If you don't specify the row headers for ratio then in what logic are you going to account for the same column? Even with your existing formula for year 2023it will return 590 that is 500+90 and not at all 39.5. Try to use the Evaluate feature from Formulas Tab --> IF(COUNTIF(I2;C1:G1)*COUNTIF(J2:J3;A2:A12)*COUNTIF(K2:K3;B2:B12);C2:G12)

Try:
=LET(
    a, COUNTIF($J$2:$J$3, $A$2:$A$12),
    b, COUNTIF($K$2, $B$2:$B$12),
    c, CHOOSECOLS($A$2:$G$12, 3, XMATCH($I$2, $A$1:$G$1)),
    SUM(a * b * CHOOSECOLS(c, 1) * CHOOSECOLS(c, 2))
)

To account for no entries in ColCrit1, or no entries in ColCrit2, you could modify it:
=LET(
    a, IF(
        COUNTA($J$2:$J$5) = 0,
        N(ISNUMBER(ROW($A$2:$A$12))),
        COUNTIF($J$2:$J$5, $A$2:$A$12)
    ),
    b, IF(
        COUNTA($K$2:$K$5) = 0,
        N(ISNUMBER(ROW($B$2:$B$12))),
        COUNTIF($K$2:$K$5, $B$2:$B$12)
    ),
    c, CHOOSECOLS($A$2:$G$12, 3, XMATCH($I$2, $A$1:$G$1)),
    SUM(a * b * CHOOSECOLS(c, 1) * CHOOSECOLS(c, 2))
)



So, try implementing the following to get desired outputs, I wasn't sure that the ratio column index should be hardcoded here:


• Using LAMBDA() helper function called BYROW()
=LET(
     α, A2:G12,
     δ, COUNTIF(J2:J3,TAKE(α,,1)),
     ε, COUNTIF(K2:K3,INDEX(α,,2)),
     φ, IFS(SUM(δ)=0,ε,SUM(ε)=0,δ,1,δ*ε),
     SUM(BYROW(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(α, φ),3,XMATCH(I2,A1:G1)),LAMBDA(a, PRODUCT(a)))))


• Or without using LAMBDA() helper functions:
=LET(
     α, A2:G12,
     δ, COUNTIF(J2:J3,TAKE(α,,1)),
     ε, COUNTIF(K2:K3,INDEX(α,,2)),
     φ, IFS(SUM(δ)=0,ε,SUM(ε)=0,δ,1,δ*ε),
     Σ, CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(α, φ),3,XMATCH(I2,A1:G1)),
     SUMPRODUCT(TAKE(Σ,,1)*TAKE(Σ,,-1)))


Use Case One: --> When ColCrit1 is empty


Use Case Two: --> When ColCrit2 is empty


Similar idea drawn from last answer of OP's post: Using a list (range) of column criteria (not single cells) in FILTER formula

One more way using Custom LAMBDA() + MMULT() :
=LET(
     λ,LAMBDA(α,δ,ABS(AND(ISBLANK(δ))-MMULT(--(α=TOROW(δ)),{1;1}))),
   SUM(FILTER(E2:G12,E1:G1=I2)*C2:C12*λ(A2:A12,J2:J3)*λ(B2:B12,K2:K3)))



A version using SUMPRODUCT, COUNTIF and FILTER, and with

Criteria in multiple cells usual functionality available for COUNTIF criteria
Include all if all blanks in brands or products
Include all years if criteria is blank

Calculate the result with:
=SUMPRODUCT(
_filter_by_year,
_ratios,
_include(_brands, _col_crit_1),
_include(_products, _col_crit_2))

Create the following named ranges and functions (these will be available in all the sheets in the workbook):



Name
Refers to




_data
=SO_74776702!$A$1:$G$12


_brands
=INDEX(DROP(_data,1),,1)


_col_crit_1
=SO_74776702!$J$2:$J$5


_col_crit_2
=SO_74776702!$K$2:$K$5


_row_crit
=SO_74776702!$I$2:$I$5


_years
=TAKE(DROP(_data,,4),1)


_products
=INDEX(DROP(_data,1),,2)


_ratios
=DROP(TAKE(DROP(_data,,2),,1),1)






_filter_by_year
=LET(_yd, DROP(_data,1, 4),   _filtered, IF(_all_blanks(_row_crit), _yd, FILTER(_yd,  fx_countifs_or(_years,_row_crit))),   _sum_cols(_filtered) )






_all_blanks
=LAMBDA(range, COUNTBLANK(range) = ROWS(range))


_include_all
=LAMBDA(range, IFERROR(range * 0, 0) + 1)


_include
=LAMBDA(_range,_criteria,   IF(_all_blanks(_range), _include_all(_range),  fx_countifs_or(_range,_criteria)) )


_sum_cols
=LAMBDA(_cols,BYROW(_cols,LAMBDA(_row,SUM(_row))))






fx_countifs_or
=LAMBDA(_range,_criteria, MAP(_range, LAMBDA(_row, N(OR(COUNTIF(_row, _criteria))) )))




